# Haskell trouble with recursion on ADT

Tags: haskell, scheme

I'm through chapter 8 on algebraic data types in [LYAHFGG](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and I'm running into a snag when I try to implement Scheme-like list operations.

The idea was to try build cons, car, cdr on a Pair adt, then write a standard recursion to calculate length:

```
data Pair a b =  NullPair | Pair { thisCar :: a, thisCdr :: b} deriving (Eq)

cons :: a -> b -> Pair a b
cons x y = Pair { thisCar = x, thisCdr = y}

car :: Pair a b -> a
car (Pair {thisCar = x, thisCdr = y}) = x

cdr :: Pair a b -> b
cdr (Pair {thisCar = x, thisCdr = y}) = y

instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Pair a b) where
  show NullPair = "()"
  show (Pair { thisCar=x, thisCdr=y}) = "(" ++ show x ++ " . " ++ show y ++ ")"
```

So far so good:

```
l1 = NullPair   -- ()
l2 = cons 3 NullPair  -- (3)
l3 = cons (cons 2 NullPair) (cons 3 (cons 4 NullPair))  -- ((2) 3 4)

λ> l1
()
λ> l2
(3 . ())
λ> l3
((2 . ()) . (3 . (4 . ())))
λ> car l2
3
λ> car l3
(2 . ())
λ> cdr l2
()
λ> cdr l3
(3 . (4 . ()))
λ> cdr (cdr l3)
(4 . ())
```

Note that the REPL did not complain when I entered cdr (cdr l3).  More on that in a bit...

So here is my length function (and we assume the input is a set of nested pairs whose innermost thisCdr is NullPair) and the error I get when I try to compile it.

```
len :: Pair a b -> Integer
len NullPair = 0
len p = 1 + len $ thisCdr p

lists.hs:117:19-27: error: …
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Pair a0 b0’ with actual type ‘b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          len :: forall a b. Pair a b -> Integer
        at /home/nate/Documents/haskell/ProblemSets/lists.hs:115:8
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘thisCdr p’
      In the expression: 1 + len $ thisCdr p
      In an equation for ‘len’: len p = 1 + len $ thisCdr p
    • Relevant bindings include
        p :: Pair a b
          (bound at /home/nate/Documents/haskell/ProblemSets/lists.hs:117:5)
        len :: Pair a b -> Integer
          (bound at /home/nate/Documents/haskell/ProblemSets/lists.hs:116:1)
Compilation failed.
```

My interpretation is that I'm telling the compiler to look for something of type Pair a b, but it's finding something of type b, and doesn't trust me that b will actually be a stand-in for Pair a b.  What's also puzzling is that it has no problem with cdr (cdr l3), even though cdr returns a value of type b, but expects a value of type Pair a b.

So:

1. Can someone explain in technical terms what is going on here? Clearly I'm not grasping something about the type system. Or quite possibly my code is flawed.
2. Is there away around this? Maybe a better method of performing this
   kind of recursion?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: What do you want `len (cons True False)` to be?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica like I mentioned, the input to len is a Pair that contains NullPair as its innermost thisCdr.  So, I wouldn't run len on (cons True False).  However, I would want len (cons True (cons False NullPair)) to return 2.

Comment: But the type variable from `thisCdr  :: b` is not guaranteed to be of type `Pair`. Remember `len` expects a `Pair` type only.

Comment: "I wouldn't run len on (cons True False)" But with the type signature `len :: Pair a b -> Integer`, you **could**, and that's what the compiler cares about. As such, you need to rethink your types.

Answer (score 3):

I think your interpretation is mostly right! Let me clarify a few things.

## Why doesn't your definition of `len` work?

First, when you declare a function with type variables (like the `a` and `b` in `Pair a b`), your function must work for any choice of `a` or `b`. That's why in the error message you see, the compiler says

```
...
        the type signature for:
          len :: forall a b. Pair a b -> Integer
...
```

The `forall` is something that is implicit in Haskell when we write `Pair a b`.

So the compiler is mad at you because you're trying to use a specific kind of `b` (namely, a `Pair a0 b0`), but your function wouldn't work if `b` was, say, `Int`.

## Why does `cdr (cdr l3)` work?

That's because the compiler knows what the type of `l3` is. When you apply `cdr` to it, you get back something of the form `Pair a b`, so the second application works.

You can ask the compiler to infer what the types of these functions would be. Notice how they require a more specific type than just `Pair a b`.

```
Prelude> cddr x = cdr (cdr x)
Prelude> :t cddr
cddr :: Pair a1 (Pair a2 b) -> b
Prelude> caddr x = car (cdr (cdr x))
Prelude> :t caddr
caddr :: Pair a1 (Pair a2 (Pair a3 b)) -> a3
```

Things are slightly complicated by the fact that the compiler infers that `NullPair` has the very general type `forall a b. Pair a b`. When it's passed as an *argument*, the `a` and `b` can be chosen so that the expression type checks. So any arbitrary use of `car` and `cdr`s on `NullPair` like `car (car (cdr NullPair))` will type check. There's a duality between these `forall`s when they're given to functions and when they're expected by functions. But if this explanation confuses, you can ignore it for now.

## How do you get around it?

I would recommend making your data type explicitly recursive. This loses some generality in how you can use your `Pair` data type, but it would be hard to write `len` otherwise.

```hs
data Pair a = NullPair | Pair{ thisCar :: a, thisCdr :: Pair a }
```

Now any function you write will know that `thisCdr` is has the form `Pair a`.

(You might notice that this is just the definition of lists with different names).

## If you really want to keep the definition of `Pair` the same

I wouldn't recommend this, but if you really wanted to keep your definition of `Pair` the same, here's how you can fix it.

Define the data type

```hs
data Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
```

The name `Fix` is customary (as far as I can tell) for a datatype like this; I'm not calling that because it's the solution to your problem. You can think of it as a "recursion" datatype (if you know about the *function* `fix`, this is its analogue for types).

Now we can use it to put the recursion into `Pair`.

```hs
len :: Fix (Pair a) -> Integer
len (Fix NullPair) = 0
len (Fix p) = 1 + (len $ thisCdr p)
```

If we were to examine the type of `p`, we'd see that it is `p :: Pair a (Fix (Pair a))`. In general, something of type `Fix (Pair a)` looks like

```
Fix (Pair a) = Fix (Pair a (Fix (Pair a)))
             = Fix (Pair a (Fix (Pair a (Fix (Pair a)))))
             = ...
```

This gives us the "infinite type" that the compiler was complaining about in your first definition of `len`. Although I use quotation marks since the type can be written out finitely.

Note that `Fix (Pair a)` is equivalent to the explicitly recursive definition of `Pair` I suggested in the section above. So in a sense, this is the same solution, just with the recursive datatype made more explicit (or confusing, perhaps).

Comment: Ah, brilliant!  Thank you for the thorough answer @cole.  This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
1 + len $ thisCdr p
```

parses as

```
(1 + len) $ (thisCdr p)
```

As you can guess, trying to add 1 to the function len makes little sense, and applying the result as a function is about as hopeless. What you want is

```
1 + len (thisCdr p)
```

Comment: You're right about that being a problem, but it still doesn't work even after fixing that.

Comment: Indeed, the `Pair a b` discussed in the comments above is another problem.